# Selection correction variable (non-randomly selected sample / bias) and Cox regression

Tags: survival, stata, bias, cox-model, hazard

I found an approach to calculate a selection correction variable for a Cox regression (Lee 1983. [Generalized econometric models with selectivity](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1912003?uid=3739776&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104014221997). Econometrica 51: 507–512.):
$$
λ = \phi  \frac{ \phi^{-1}   (F_i(t)) }{1 - (F_i(t))}
$$
where $F_i(t)$ is the cumulative hazard function for object $i$ at time $t$,  $\phi$ is the standard normal density function (of the selection correction variable?), and  $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the standard normal distribution function.

So far so good. However, I am quite struggling with the calculation in STATA (11). If Lamda is included as covariate, STATA says:

> flat region resulting in a missing likelihood r(430);

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue or are there any other methods to correct selection bias in Cox proportional hazard model (e.g., Heckman's correction)? Is the two-stage approach applicable and how does it work regarding the use of Cox regression?